# Not able to edit existing date in a file using awk in linux

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I am trying to convert date from format `30 January 2015` to `30012015` using below command. The original format is present in even line of a file. I want only that line to be changed. Can someone pls help me.

```
awk '{if(NR%2==1){print $0 > "file.txt"}else{print now=$("$0" +%d%m%Y') > "file.txt"}}' file.txt
```

Comment: You are reading from the file and writing to it at the same time - and to make matters worse, you use the `>` operator, which truncates the file before writing to it. You should use the append operator (`>>`) and write first to a temporary file, and then overwrite the original with the temporary. Or, if your version of `awk(1)` supports it, use the `-i` command-line option.

Comment: I tried with >>, and redirecting things to new file, but t didn't help and I was getting syntax errors.

Answer (score 0):

you can try,

```
echo -e "whatever\n30 January 2015" | awk '
BEGIN{
    m=split("January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December",d,"|");
    for(i=1;i<=m;i++) months[d[i]]=i;
}
NR%2 { print; next }
{
    printf "%02d%02d%04d\n",$1,months[$2],$3;
}'
```

you get,

```
whatever
30012015
```